# Delete from multiple columns in one single query

Tags: database

Will you help me with this:

in DB `vot` I have tables `blocked`и `comments`

what I want is to delete where:
`blocked`.`friend`  =$_SESSION['user_id']
`comments`.`user`=$_SESSION['user_id']

IN ONE SINGLE query

Comment: you want to delete from both databases ?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible for make in one query.

For correct solution you can use Transaction or create FK cascade keys.